# Notation and Proof: Sets

Tags: notation

List all eight subsets of the set $$A=\{3,5,7\}$$.

Let $$A=\{j,m,h\}$$ Explain why $\{A\}$ is not a subset of $A$.

We notice that the given set $A$ is finite. It contains three elements: 3, 5 and 7.

Comment: Did you mean to label both sets as $ A $ ?

Comment: @QthePlatypus Yes. Anything else that is unclear please do not hesitate to ask

Comment: What gave you the impression that A is not a subset of itself? The eight subsets of A include both A and the empty set.

Comment: Unfortunately, *all* of this is unclear. What do you mean "first eight sets of $A$"? Are you asking for all eight subsets of $A$? And what does $A = \{j, m, h\}$ have to do with the definition of $A$, and how do you use it to come to the (wrong) conclusion that $A$ is not a subset of $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every set includes itself as a subset. A is a subset of A so the subsets of A are

$ \mathbb{P}(A) = \{
\{\},
\{3\}, \{5\}, \{7\},
\{3, 5\}, \{3, 7\}, \{5, 7\},
\{3, 5, 7\} \}
$

Comment: What of the $A\{j,m,h\}$? Should we presume that the set $A$ is variable and can take on any integers?

Comment: Since  $ A = \{3,4,7\} = \{j, m, h\} $ then j must be one of 3, 4 or 7.  However it shouldn't matter to the question.  What motivated you to add that part.  if I knew where it came from I could give a better answer.

Comment: Much obliged. Thanks for the help.